# Understand the meaning of Unix shell script call

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a Unix shell script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar lib/<some_jar_file_name_here>.jar $* > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

When I run this script, I pass one command line argument.

I want to understand the meaning of `$*`, `>`, `/dev/null` and `2>&1 &`

What is the meaning of the extra charaters after the jar file name?

Comment: In general `"$@"` (with quotes) is preferred over `$*` -- if you pass a parameter that contains whitespace, the first form will keep your parameters intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$*` expands to all the parameters passed into the script.

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` (the output stream where error messages are usually sent to) into `stdout` (the output stream usually used for "normal output").

`> /dev/null` sends the `stdout` to the `null` device, effectively ignoring it. Since we also redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, we're also sending `stderr` output to `/dev/null`.

`2>&1 >/dev/null` (or `>/dev/null 2>&1`) are very common patterns and effrectively means "I don't want to see any console output from this application!"

`&` executes the call to `java` in the background, so that execution continues on the next line of the script instead of waiting for `java` to return.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Helpful. What is the meaning of '/dev/null'

Comment: Forgot that. Just added to the answer

Answer (score 3):

The shell treats several parameters specially. These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.

`$*` Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a separate word. In contexts where it is performed, those words are subject to further word splitting and pathname expansion. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c…", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

`> /dev/null 2>&1`

Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected using a special notation interpreted by  the  shell.   Redirection  may  also  be used to open and close files for the current shell execution environment.  The following redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple  command or may follow a command.  Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to right.

Redirecting Output
    Redirection of output causes the file whose name results from the expansion of  word  to  be  opened  for writing  on  file descriptor n, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not specified.  If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.

The general format for redirecting output is:

```
       [n]>word
```

If the redirection operator is >, and the noclobber option to the  set  builtin  has  been  enabled,  the
    redirection  will  fail if the file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and is a regular file.  If the redirection operator is >|, or the redirection operator is > and the  noclobber  option  to the  set  builtin  command  is  not  enabled, the redirection is attempted even if the file named by word exists.

`/dev/null` - standard file that discards all you write to it, but reports that the write operation succeeded. 1 is stdout and 2 is stderr

`&`

If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return  status  is  0.

Answer (score 1):

`$*` - means "all cmd line parameters"

`2>&1` - means "redirect STDERR to STDOUT"

`> /dev/null` - means "ignore and don't print script's output"

`&` at the end means "send process to background". in this case is you end your terminal session, the process will be killed